# Parsing in a R Data Frame by columns, not by sep

Tags: r

I have Two Line Element data https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/ that I have made single line, resulting in 1,00s of rows of 160 numbers and characters.  Unlike a CSV there are no separators.  Using R, how do I parse the data into the correct column width?  Here is an example of the data, and some of the first columns.
1 00011U 59001A   18243.16403752  .00000112 
123456789012345678901234567890
...    col#   content
1   01–01   Line number,example - 1
2   03–07   Satellite number, example - 25544
3   08–08   Classification (U=Unclassified), example - U
4   10–11   Intl Designator (Last two digits of launch year), example - 98
5   12–14   Intl Designator (Launch number - year),example - 067
6   15–17   Intl Designator (piece of the launch), example - A

thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can parse these kinds of "fixed width format" files in R using `read.fwf()`. You have to specify the width of each column, I'm having a little bit of trouble matching your example data to the column descriptions you provided but this mostly works:

```
read.fwf(
    textConnection("1 00011U 59001A 18243.16403752 .00000112"), 
    widths = c(2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4),
    # Just reading everything as a string for the moment
    colClasses = "character"
)
```

Output:

```
  V1    V2 V3 V4  V5   V6
1 1  00011 U  59 001 A 18
```